# Getting value of Combobox on Hover c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to make an application where I have this combobox that automatically opens and closes on mouse enter and mouse leave events respectively and then gets the value of the combobox before i leave it.

I already have the dropdown behavior as given by someone who posted it online. But now I need to get the value of my combobox item without clicking the mouse. I've tried `selectedvalue` or `selecteditem` but all seems to require mouse clicking. Is there any way of getting the value of the combobox where the mouse points to before I leave/close the combobox?

Comment: Tried that too. But it returns -1/null just the same.

Comment: For the fisrt time or also for the next times?

Comment: So in the Loading put the first item in the property SelectedItem

Comment: Hmmm...but that still require clicking when i need to change what i want to select.

Comment: I dont understand.you want to change items in combobox without clicking or you want to get the current selected item?

Comment: i want to get the current item pointed by the mouse without clicking.

Comment: So what the problem with this solution? the loading is done one time without clicking. According to my understanding your problem is in the first time becouse there isn't SelectedItem yet. so you can set this propery in the loading event or in the properties. like : cb_a.SelectedItem = cb_a.Items[0];

Comment: yep. i did that already. But when i want to change the item again, for example from cb_a.Items[0] to cb_a.Items[2], i need to click the mouse first before cb_a.SelectedItem can be changed. But my program needs to change the SelectedItem without the need of mouse clicking but instead just by hovering to the item which i am having problem on.

Comment: @user1176356 What do you want? First you are stating you want to get the value of the combobox, next you are stating you wanting to set it.

Comment: Oh i got it. I just need to add PreviewMouseMove for each comboboxitem. Aryt. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels for the combobox items.

Add 'MouseMove' event and in the event take the label text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to implement very closely connected behavior: [ComboBox MouseLeave MouseEnter](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/194250.aspx).